# Swift 3.0 - Broken func value(for component: Calendar.Component) -> Int?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Is there a workaround for value(for component: Calendar.Component) seemingly being broken? Or a dynamic way to call the property version?

```
func dateComponentsValueShouldBeNil() {
     let dateComponents = DateComponents(month: 3)
     debugPrint("Month", dateComponents.month) // "Month" Optional(3)
     debugPrint("Property", dateComponents.hour) // "Property" nil
     debugPrint("Enumeration", dateComponents.value(for: .hour)) // "Enumeration" Optional(9223372036854775807)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Non-defined date components in a `DateComponents` instance (valued `nil` there) are represented in the wrapped `NSDateComponents` instance by the global `int` property `NSDateComponentUndefined`

This is not a bug/broken method, but follows from the fact that `DateComponents` is tighly connected to `NSDateComponents` (which derives from `NSObject`: not using optionals an `nil` to specify objects with no value). Specifically, the former's `value(...)` method is, principally, a wrapper for the latter's `value(forComponent:)` method ([API Reference: Foundation -> NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatecomponents/1416763-value))

> ```
> value(forComponent:)
> ```
>
> Returns the value for a given NSCalendarUnit value.
>
> **Declaration**
>
> ```
> func value(forComponent unit: NSCalendar.Unit) -> Int
> ```

This method cannot return `nil`, but represents date components without a value by the [global `int` variable `NSDateComponentUndefined`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatecomponentundefined).

```
let dateComponents = DateComponents(month: 3)
debugPrint("Enumeration", dateComponents.value(for: .hour))
    // "Enumeration" Optional(9223372036854775807)
debugPrint("NSDateComponentUndefined", NSDateComponentUndefined)
    // "NSDateComponentUndefined" 9223372036854775807
```

From [API Reference: Foundation -> NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatecomponents) we read:

> ...
>
> An `NSDateComponents` object is not required to define all the component
>   fields. When a new instance of `NSDateComponents` is created the date
>   components are set to `NSDateComponentUndefined`.

Hence, the return for attempting to call `value(...)` for a `Calendar.Component` member of `DateComponents` that has not been initialized is not gibberish, but the default undefined value `NSDateComponentUndefined` (a global `int` property which happens return/be set to `Int64.max = 9223372036854775807`).

---

To dwell deeper into the details of this, we may visit the source of `DateComponents` ([swift-corelibs-foundation/Foundation/DateComponents.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/DateComponents.swift))

```
/// Set the value of one of the properties, using an enumeration value instead of a property name.
///
/// The calendar and timeZone and isLeapMonth properties cannot be set by this method.
public mutating func setValue(_ value: Int?, for component: Calendar.Component) {
    _applyMutation {
        $0.setValue(_setter(value), forComponent: Calendar._toCalendarUnit([component]))
    }
}

/// Returns the value of one of the properties, using an enumeration value instead of a property name.
///
/// The calendar and timeZone and isLeapMonth property values cannot be retrieved by this method.
public func value(for component: Calendar.Component) -> Int? {
    return _handle.map {
        $0.value(forComponent: Calendar._toCalendarUnit([component]))
    }
}
```

property `_handle` above wraps `NSDateComponents`

```
internal var _handle: _MutableHandle<NSDateComponents>
```

in a `_MutableHandle` ([swift-corelibs-foundation/Foundation/Boxing.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/Boxing.swift))

```
internal final class _MutableHandle<MutableType : NSObject> where MutableType : NSCopying {
    fileprivate var _pointer : MutableType

    // ...

    /// Apply a closure to the reference type.
    func map<ReturnType>(_ whatToDo : (MutableType) throws -> ReturnType) rethrows -> ReturnType {
        return try whatToDo(_pointer)
    }

    // ...
}
```

From the signature of `value(...)` above `ReturnType` is inferred to as `Int?`, and `_toCalendarValue` is defined as ([swift-corelibs-foundation/Foundation/Calendar.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/Calendar.swift))

```
internal static func _toCalendarUnit(_ units: Set<Component>) -> NSCalendar.Unit {
    let unitMap: [Component : NSCalendar.Unit] =
        [.era: .era,
         .year: .year,
         .month: .month,
         .day: .day,
         .hour: .hour,
         .minute: .minute,
         .second: .second,
         .weekday: .weekday,
         .weekdayOrdinal: .weekdayOrdinal,
         .quarter: .quarter,
         .weekOfMonth: .weekOfMonth,
         .weekOfYear: .weekOfYear,
         .yearForWeekOfYear: .yearForWeekOfYear,
         .nanosecond: .nanosecond,
         .calendar: .calendar,
         .timeZone: .timeZone]

    var result = NSCalendar.Unit()
    for u in units {
        let _ = result.insert(unitMap[u]!)
    }
    return result
}
```

Hence, `whatToDo` in the body of the return of `value(...)` can be deciphered to be equivalent to a call to

```
NSDateComponents.value(forComponent: NSCalendar.Unit)
```

And as descriped in the top of this answer, this call can never return `nil` (return type `Int`).

If we, finally, return to the source of [`DateComponents`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/DateComponents.swift), we see that the following private getter and setter handles the "bridging" between `NSDateComponentUndefined` and `nil`.

```
/// Translate from the NSDateComponentUndefined value into a proper Swift optional
private func _getter(_ x : Int) -> Int? { return x == NSDateComponentUndefined ? nil : x }

/// Translate from the proper Swift optional value into an NSDateComponentUndefined
private func _setter(_ x : Int?) -> Int { if let xx = x { return xx } else { return NSDateComponentUndefined } }
```

Comment: This was reported as a bug, if anyone's interested: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2671

Comment: This has now become a little inconvenient again, as with Xcode 10.2 code coverage has become a bit stricter (at least in my context). In my project I provide a default value (0) for this, but I can't mock that for my unit tests, so there's no way to test the code responsible for handling that `value(for:)` returns `nil`. Bummer... Still, thanks a lot for digging into this (even if it was over 2 years ago) and confirming it should never actually become `nil`, despite the method signature.

Comment: This _is_ a bug though. It is not a bug in `NSDateComponents` but it _is_ a bug in `DateComponents`. It is the responsibility of the swift bridging of the objc method to translate `NSDateComponentUndefined` to `nil`. When the Swift class' documentation says that it returns an optional value but makes no mention of a _magic_ return value and does not return `nil` for an undefined result that is a bug.

Comment: It is also not idempotent. For example, if you set a break point in code that calls `DateComponents.value(for: .year)` and inspect the result before and after calling `DateComponents.value(for: .yearForWeekOfYear)` you get `Int64.max` on the first call and `nil` on all subsequent calls.